# Javascript library for both the browser and node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, node.js

I want to write a javascript library that works like an SDK for an external API.
Ideally this library could be used both for frontend projects, in the browser and for backend projects using node.js.
Initally I wasn't considering node so I was planning to require jquery as a dependency for using the ajax functions (for making the API calls) and deffered objects, but now I have second thaughts.
Considering that my goal is to have the same code base for both scenarios what do you think I should do? Is using the jquery npm package a good idea, or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: So you'd be using jQuery just for the AJAX and deferreds? That doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: Yes... the thing is that in the browser the projects where we'll be using this library already use or will use jQuery, so it wont be a problem. But in node it seems a bit out of place to require jQuery just for this... that's why I was asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jquery` package from the npm repo without problems.